# baseMapWidget on smartgwt project with ArcGis

Tags: java, javascript, dictionary, smartgwt, arcgis

I've got a smartgwt project which contains baseMapWidget map object. I wanna get actual map state to the png file. how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you have to use PrintTask class.